# Как втавить на форму в ларавел видео?

Tags: laravel

Как отобразить на форме видео, картинку я отображаю таким образом

```
 <img src="{{url('storage/' . $task->image_task)}}" width="150" height="150" alt="Открыть файл" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Через img вы отображаете картинку видео можете попробовать вставив через [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://playerjs.com)

```
 <video width="360" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ URL_VIDEO}}" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```